# Has anyone found a USB to DVI adaptor that works on Windows XP x64?

Tags: usb, dvi

Has anyone found a USB to DVI adaptor that works on Windows XP x64?  Tried looking around and can't find one in google.  Bought a random one and I can't install the drivers on XP x64.

Comment: I'm not aware of any with XPx64 support either.  Just one more reason it's a terrible operating system.  Upgrade.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately the problem you are going to run into is that almost every USB DVI adapter is using a DisplayLink chip-set (including the one mentioned by Wizlog, and the EVGA one from the other question;  I've not actually seen one that doesn't).  And so they all use DisplayLink's drivers, and DisplayLink has not released a XP 64-bit driver (and has no plans to).

See their support forums, specifically [this answer](http://www.displaylink.org/forum/showpost.php?p=1063&postcount=11):

> As stated in my previous posts, we would only want to consider releasing a fully productized solution. Windows 7 is now our main focus for development and we have no plans for any specific Windows XP work.

That was in 2008. :)

[Here's the official list](http://www.displaylink.com/support/ticket.php?id=160) of OS's DisplayLink does and doesn't support:

> DisplayLink software does *not* install on:
>
> - Windows 2000 (SP1 to SP3)
> - Windows 2003 Server
> - Windows XP Embedded
> - Windows XP (No service pack)
> - Windows XP SP1
> - **Windows XP 64 bit**
> - Windows 2008 Server
> - Windows 2008 Server RC2

Comment: This is the long version of my comment on the question.  They're all essentially the same, and the vendor doesn't support it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is a cheaper one, but [this](http://eshop.macsales.com/item/Other+World+Computing/VIDU2DVIA/) will work (it may do too much for you... but... it'll get the job done.

Comment: Just to confirm, you have used this on the 64 bit version of XP?